# Python error: TypeError: 'list' object does not support indexing

Tags: python

I'm testing out a bit of a code that I'm going to use for a simple game but I get this error `in init gamefield[x][y] = tecken TypeError: 'field' object does not support indexing`

The game is somewhat similar to snake and What I want my program to do is to first create a gamefield which is a matrix where I want to insert my snake(I call it worm here) which is represented by "+", the position should be chosen randomly.

I then want to be able to decide in which direction the worm grow hence the grow function.

Can anyone see what's the problem in here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import random

class field:
    def __init__(self):

        self.table= [ [ "0" for i in range(10) ] for j in range(10) ]



def printfield(self):
    for row in self.table:
            print (row)
class worm:
    def __init__(self,tecken):

        x = random.randint(1,9) 
        y = random.randint(1,9)
        gamefield[x][y] = tecken

    def grow(self,p,b,c):             
            try :               

                for antal in range(p):
                    if p != 0:      
                        gamefield[x-antal*b][y-antal*c] = "+"    

            except IndexError :
                print ("Game Over")


p = 2
b = 3
c = 0
gamefield = field()
hilda = worm("+")
hilda.grow(p,b,c)

print(gamefield.printfield)
```

Comment: There is no `spelplan` in your code.  Please post the full error message that comes from the actual code you posted.

Comment: I assume `spelplan` is gamefield in a German-like language.

Comment: Oh, sorry guys. I think the code is updated now but I just thought I Should translate it from Swedish to English before posting here but I guess I missed something there! 

Here is the full error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Allt/Programmering/Test/astrakan.py", line 35, in <module>
    hilda = worm("+")
  File "C:/Allt/Programmering/Test/astrakan.py", line 18, in __init__
    gamefield[x][y] = tecken
TypeError: 'field' object does not support indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list is `gamefield.table`. `gamefield` itself is not indexable.

If you want to, you can define `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, so as to wrap the operations on `table`. Alternatively, you can simply instantiate `gamefield` as your list of lists instead of making it a separate type of object.

Comment: Oh, I see! I'll try change to gamefield.table . 
How would I do that?

Comment: I ment, how would I instantiate gamefield instead of making it a separate object?

Comment: I suppose you could do `gamefield = [ [ "0" for i...`